# How to read data table column by column from a txt in python

Tags: python, datatable

so basically I need to read a file in, and display the result column by column, and example input and output is shown below, along with the my code.

this is the txt file:

```
  Name  ID  City    Favorite Fruit
Benjamin    5   Copenhagen  kiwi
Tom 100 Kingston    "watermelon, apple"
Rosemary    20  Philadelphia    "pineapple, mango"
Annie   95  East Setauket   "blueberry, hawthorn"
Jonathan    75  Ithaca  cherry
Kathryn 40  San Francisco   "banana, strawberry"
```

and this is the output:

```
Number of rows: 7
Number of columns: 4
Column 0: Name
 1 Annie
 1 Benjamin
 1 Jonathan
 1 Kathryn
 1 Rosemary
 1 Tom
Column 1: ID
 1 5
 1 20
 1 40
 1 75
 1 95
 1 100
Column 2: City
1 Copenhagen
1 East Setauket
1 Ithaca
1 Kingston
1 Philadelphia
1 San Francisco
Column 3: Favorite Fruit
 1 "banana, strawberry"
1 "blueberry, hawthorn"
 1 "pineapple, mango"
 1 "watermelon, apple"
 1 cherry
 1 kiwi
```

and the below is my code, i got stuck at how to print the table out column by column:

```
import sys
def main():
    alist =[]
    data = open("a1input1.txt").read()
    lines = data.split('\n')
    totalline =len(lines)
    print ("Number of low is: " + str(totalline))
    column = lines[0].split('\t')
    totalcolumn = len(column)
    print ("Number of column is: " + str(totalcolumn))
    for index in range(totalline):
        column = lines[index].split('\t')
        print (column)
 main()
```

below is what I got doing: newlist.sort(), the name column is sorted, but the ID column is not. all these vales are reading from a txt file. I don't get why only the ID column is not sorted?

```
Column 0: Name
Annie
Benjamin
Jonathan
Kathryn
Rosemary
Tom
Column 1: ID
100
20
40
5
75
95
```

I have tried to convert the string using the "str()", but the result is the same

Comment: yes, I just need someone to point me in the right direction, I do not know where to go from here on, how to read or separate them by column

Comment: Are they separated by tabs, or spaces?

Comment: the columns are separated by tab, rows are by line

Comment: You should tell your teacher off for using inconsistent syntax. One column is enclosed in spaces if it contains a space and another does not.

Comment: I wish I can, she will skin me alive. LOL

Comment: @StephenPaulger, if I were a teacher, and I wanted my students to think carefully about delimiters -- specifically, to distinguish between space and tab -- I might also use inconsistent syntax. Makes it easier to tell that someone has got it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another hint... If you want to iterate over columns instead of rows, transpose the data using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).  I'll leave it up to you to get the data in the right format:

```
data = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(data)
data = list(zip(*data))
print(data)
```

#### Output

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[('a', 1, 4, 7), ('b', 2, 5, 8), ('c', 3, 6, 9)]
```

The above assumes Python 3 judging by your use of `print()` as a function...

Answer (score 5):

You can use python in-built csv module and save yourself a lot of nasty looking code.

```
import csv
data = open("data", "rb")
csv_dict = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter="\t", quotechar="\"")
```

This will give you an object that you can iterate over to get a dict of the values.

```
>>> for item in csv_dict:
...     print item
... 
{'City': 'Copenhagen', 'Favorite Fruit': 'kiwi', 'Name': 'Benjamin', 'ID': '5'}
{'City': 'Kingston', 'Favorite Fruit': 'watermelon, apple', 'Name': 'Tom', 'ID': '100'}
{'City': 'Philadelphia', 'Favorite Fruit': 'pineapple, mango', 'Name': 'Rosemary', 'ID': '20'}
{'City': 'East Setauket', 'Favorite Fruit': 'blueberry, hawthorn', 'Name': 'Annie', 'ID': ' 95'}
{'City': 'Ithaca', 'Favorite Fruit': 'cherry', 'Name': 'Jonathan', 'ID': '75'}
{'City': 'San Francisco', 'Favorite Fruit': 'banana, strawberry', 'Name': 'Kathryn', 'ID': '40'}
```

and you can get a list of the headers

```
>>> csv_dict.fieldnames
['Name', 'ID', 'City', 'Favorite Fruit']
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here are some hints:

```
>>> s = 'a \tb \tc \td\ne \tf \tg \th'
>>> s.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> s.split('\n')
['a \tb \tc \td', 'e \tf \tg \th']
>>> rows = [x.split() for x in s.split('\n')]
>>> rows
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
>>> [row[0] for row in rows]
['a', 'e']
>>> [row[1] for row in rows]
['b', 'f']
```

Comment: thank you. I got it to work now. but the problem is how to sort them, I try to sort is by "wholelist= wholelist.sort()
    print(wholelist)" but its giving me a message: "<built-in method sort of list object at 0x027D9508>" nothing is being printed

Comment: @user1099029 Make sure you actually had parentheses after `sort`.  `print(wholelist.sort)` reproduces your error.  Also, `sort` is an in-place method and returns None, so use `wholelist.sort()` not `wholelist=wholelist.sort()`.